# Finding the missing values in a trigonometric theoretical scenario? Rocket launch?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

For my pre-calculus class, I am tasked with sketching a diagram illustrating a scenario as well as determining the angle of elevation after the object is "x" meters above the ground.

The prompt is:

> A television camera at ground level is filming the lift-off of a space shuttle at a point
>   625 meters from the launch pad. Let $\theta$ be the angle of elevation from the camera to
>   the shuttle, and let s be the height of the shuttle. Sketch a diagram illustrating this
>   scenario. Then determine the angle of elevation (in radians, to the nearest hundredth)
>   when the shuttle is 500 meters above the ground.

Currently I am at a stand-still with this problem for some reason. But this is what I know:

- The camera is 625 meters from the launch pad
- $\theta$ is the angle of elevation from the camera to the shuttle
- $s$ is the height of the shuttle

The sketch that I have drawn so far is this: 
[rocket sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUgVT.jpg)

I am not sure if this is correct, if it is not, please let me know. I am not sure what they want, not that you all would but do you think that it simply wants a picture drawn, rather than a triangle?

After the sketch, it wants me to then determine the angle of elevation $\theta$, when the shuttle is 500 meters above the ground. I believe that I should be using tangent here, since it seems like I have the opposite (500) and the adjacent (625). From there I have $\tan\theta = \frac{500}{625}$, which equals 0.8, and then $\arctan 0.8$ gives me about 38.6958 degrees. Would this be the correct answer? If not please elaborate and explain where I went wrong and what I should do. Thank you.

Comment: The question requests "radians to the nearest hundredth"; I think most calculators recommended for a pre-calculus course will allow you to specify that you want the arc tangent in radians rather than degrees. Aside from that detail, this looks fine.

Comment: But seriously, a _space shuttle?_ That was an exciting new technology when _I_ was in high school, but the last such flight was almost five years ago and it was known to be obsolescent years before that. Someone did not keep up with the times. :-)

Comment: Haha, that is true, if you would like to bring that matter up with my teacher, feel free to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got it.

Now just convert the angle to radians:

$$38.6958^{\circ} \cdot \pi/180 \approx 0.6753691353 \text{ radians}$$

And round to the number of decimals asked for in the question.

(Actually, I'd use the "radians" mode on your calculator.  That should give you the best answer.  I'm not sure why I'm getting different values for this question but just straight $\arctan 0.8$ gives $0.67$ to two decimals.)

Comment: Awesome, thank you. One last thing, what would you imagine it wants for the "sketch". Something like what I provided? Or more like a picture having the camera drawn to the left and the rocket drawn to the right and something indicating that the two are 325m from each other?

Comment: What you drew in your sketch was fine.  It was clear and had all of the pertinent features labeled correctly.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your help and your input!